# Why can't a destructor have reference qualifiers?

Tags: c++, destructor, ref-qualifier, function-qualifier

Is there a reason (other than *because the standard says so*) to why the following code is not allowed?

```
struct Foo
{
    ~Foo() && {}
    ~Foo() & {}
};
```

I know that it is illegal, but I wanna know why.

I was thinking about the good old *avoid unnamed instances* problem, i.e. when using guard objects, like:

```
void do_something()
{
    std::lock_guard{my_mutex};
    // some synchronized operation
}
```

This is legal code but obviously error prone since the lock guard would be destroyed immediately after its construction, because it's a temporary (unnamed) object.

I was planning on doing something like this

```
struct Foo
{
    ~Foo() && = delete;
    ~Foo() & = default;
};
```

and get a compiler error if the type is constructed as a temporary.

Comment: What should be the purpose of the reference qualifiers there?

Comment: What is a kind of requirement you have?

Comment: I would say, because a destructor destroys the object. There is no reason why it should have any qualifiers. A referenced object is never destroyed. What would you do with a class using those qualifiers?

Comment: @t.niese I was thinking about ways to avoid unnamed instances. I know reference qualifiers aren't a perfect solution to this either but I figured it'd be better than nothing.

Comment: @Dr.-Ing.GerhardStein Not sure what you mean by _"A referenced object is never destroyed"_. That's where dangling references come from.

Comment: @Mannoj no requirements, just theory crafting.

Comment: @Timo I still don't see what problem this should solve. Could you probably extend your question with an example that would illustrate where this would help?

Comment: @Timo Hmm, dangling references. Well, can you give us an example where you would use your class. I think it might clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Without having the same for constructors, I don't really see the point having this.

Comment: @t.niese Added an example

Comment: @geza Indeed the constructor could also be used for my purposes, haven't thought about that.

Comment: Yes, or maybe there is some other way to do this. So, maybe it would have been better to ask "how to have a warning, if lock_guards are used as temporaries", instead of asking this question (if you have this specific problem in mind).

Comment: @geza Yeah I just had a conversation on the cpp slack channel about this. Turns out we can use `[[nodiscard]]` on ctors now which gives us a warning. If we could make `nodiscard` a keyword, that would be pretty awesome to avoid missuse of guard types imo.

Answer (score 4):

First, there must be only one destructor per class. Allowing *ref-qualifiers* on the destructor would make it possible to overload the destructor.

Another possible reason is to be consistent with [`const` and `volatile` qualifiers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2439.htm):

> A destructor shall not be declared `const`, `volatile` or `const volatile` (9.3.2). **`const` and `volatile` semantics (7.1.5.1) are not applied on *an object under destruction***.

I guess, for consistency, distinguishing between *rvalues* and *lvalues* is not applied on an object under destruction.

Comment: Interesting, would a change in that behavior (if we were to allow reference qualifiers) affect existing code?

Comment: This is just a "because the standard says so" answer, doesn't really answer the why. Of course, if we had `&` and `&&` destructors, it means overloading the destructor. This is the question about.

Comment: @Timo I think it would be backwards compatible since the existing code doesn't use it.